# Google extension error with setTimeOut and click() in javaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I made an extension that allows me to refresh a spotify page and replay a playlist. It worked very well so far but a few days ago an error appeared and I don't understand why.

This is my js code :

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("control-button spoticon-play-16 control-button--circled")[0].click();
}, 30000);
```

And here is the error that google gives me :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
content.js:3 (anonymous function)
```

My manifest :

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Spotify Replay",
    "description": "Refresh and replay the playlist when spotify crash",
    "version": "1",
    "author": "LaTouillette",
    "permissions": [
        "webNavigation"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "128": "img/128icon.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://open.spotify.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you for the help ! (I'm a beginner in js and on stackoverflow)

Comment: Maybe there is no element with all of the classes `"control-button spoticon-play-16 control-button--circled"`?

Comment: There is one, that's the class name of the spotify play button

Answer (score 0):

Did the HTML structure of your application change during that time? What is happening right now is that you're attempting to call the `click()` function on the first item in the array of HTML-elements that was returned from `document.getElementsByClassName("control-button spoticon-play-16 control-button--circled");`

But it appears that the above `getElementsByClassName` returns an empty array. Which causes your first item (`[0]`) to be `undefined`, resulting in the error *"Cannot read property 'click' of **undefined***".

You should look into your DOM to see if your HTML changed, or any class names.

Comment: I had this error : Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).click is not a function 
I'm pretty sure it's the right class name because it worked before

Comment: Can you provide the HTML structure? - Or another question; do you have a different part of JavaScript that affects any of the `control-button spoticon-play-16 control-button--circled` class names? (Like toggling one of the classes)

Comment: Sure ther is my html :
```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" /> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Spotify Replay </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
       <h1 id="active">Allez sur https://open.spotify.com/* pour activer l'addon</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>```
And I have only one js file you've already seen

Comment: Sry i tried to put my code with ctrl + K or ``` but it doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

After that kind of long period of time that data may change

So try to debug it using alert like this..

Inside the setTimeout...
var element = document.getElementsByClassName(...)
Alert(element)
If (element!= undefined) alert(element[0])